# Koin error: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException. How to fix the issue?

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I just started learning dependendy injection with Koin. Here's my repo: https://github.com/anta40/DIWithKoin

Here's the overview. First create a SessionManager class which stored and reads a string value:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidContext
import org.koin.dsl.module

val sessionModule = module {
    single { SessionManager(androidContext()) }
}

class SessionManager (context: Context) {

    private val preferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("app_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    private val MY_CUSTOM_STR = "test"

    init {
        saveStringValue("Hello world 12345")
    }

    private fun saveStringValue(content: String) {
        preferences.edit().putString(MY_CUSTOM_STR, content).apply()
    }

    fun getStringValue(): String? {
        return preferences.getString(MY_CUSTOM_STR, "")
    }
}
```

Then use Koin to inject the SessionManager class to MainActivity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.anta40.app.diwithkoin.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import org.koin.android.ext.android.inject

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val session: SessionManager by inject()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // Should print "Hello world 12345"
        binding.txtValue.text = session.getStringValue()
    }
}
```

It crashes, though. Found this error on logcat:

> Process: com.anta40.app.diwithkoin, PID: 6423
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.anta40.app.diwithkoin/com.anta40.app.diwithkoin.MainActivity}:
> org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for
> class:'com.anta40.app.diwithkoin.SessionManager'. Check your
> definitions!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the singleton or the factory method on how to get the `SessionManager`

Typically you do this from the `onCreate` in your `Application` class:

```kotlin
class YourApp : Application() {


    override fun onCreate() {
       startKoin {
           androidContext(app)
           androidLogger()
           val modules = listOf(
               module { 
                  /*or however you construct it*/
                  factory<SessionManager>{ SessionManager(get()) }
               }
           )
           loadKoinModules(modules)
       }
    }

}
```

The sample provided was using koin `2.1.5`